# TUN/TAP Will not load

Tags: kernel, openvpn, kernel-modules, openvz

I have an OpenVZ server but can't seem to get the tun/tap module to load.

I ran `modprode tun` on the hostnode but when I go under the VM I get:

```
Tue Sep 24 03:08:36 2013 Note: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: Operation not permitted (errno=1)
Tue Sep 24 03:08:36 2013 /sbin/ip link set dev  up mtu 1500
```

Kernel:

```
2.6.32-042stab079.4 #1 SMP Thu Jul 18 18:57:29 MSK 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Do you have `/dev/net/tun` on the "host" system? You can also try to create that special file with `mknod` - it is a character device, maj 10, min 200.

Comment: Yep. It is there. I tried to create it but it was there.

Comment: What are the access permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try following

https://openvz.org/VPN_via_the_TUN/TAP_device ?

Meanwhile I'd close this question, cause it clearly shows lack of efforts to resolve the problem before asking question.